# CIFS mount as user : locked file messages on applications

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I have a samba share on a Windows machine that I want to mount to my Kubuntu 21.10 machine.

Here is the line i put in my fstab :

> //XX.XX.XX.XX/Folder /mnt/VM-Folder/ cifs credentials=/home/username/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,forceuid,forcegid,users,noauto,rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noperm,iocharset=utf8 0 0

I have tried several versions of this line and this is the best I got.

The issue that I have here is that when I open one of the file (for example a ppt file with Libreoffice, I get the following error message :

> Document file 'Doc.ppt' is locked for editing by:
>
> Unknown User
>
> Open document read-only or open a copy of the document for editing.
> Select Notify to open read-only and get notified when the document
> becomes editable.

When I look at the file, I see 777 permission and I am effectively the owner of the file and the group is correct.

I get the same sort of messages with other files (.txt).

Any idea what is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Does adding the `nobrl` option to your cifs declaration fix this issue?

```
//XX.XX.XX.XX/Folder /mnt/VM-Folder/ cifs credentials=/home/username/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,forceuid,forcegid,users,noauto,rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noperm,iocharset=utf8,nobrl 0 0
```